# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ is convergent for nonnegative $a_n$ and $a_n\neq1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent for nonnegative $a_n$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ is convergent for nonnegative $a_n$ and $a_n\neq1$.
I thought using ratio test. $\sum a_n$ is convergent so $limSup |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| < 1$ and $limSup |\frac{1-a_n}{1-a_{n+1}}| < 1$ if $a_n , a_{n+1} > 1$ and $a_n, a_{n+1} < 1$ so:$$|\frac{\frac{a_{n+1}}{1-a_{n+1}}}{\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}}| = |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\frac{1-a_n}{1-a_{n+1}}| < 1$$
1) is it true that for these conditions, $\sum\frac{a_n}{1-a_{n+1}}$ is convergent?
2) what if $a_n > 1$ and $a_{n+1} < 1$?

Comment: $\sum a_n$ convergent does **not** imply that $\limsup |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $0< \frac {a_n} {1-a_n} <2a_n$ for $n \geq $ some $n_0$ (because $a_n \to 0$).  First few terms have no effect on the  convergence of  a series.

This argument applies to your second series also.